# Constructing a closed set in $[0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Statement: Let $E:= [0,1] \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Given $\epsilon>0$ construct a closed subset $F \subset E$ such that the exterior measure $m_*(E \setminus F)<\epsilon$.

$\textbf{Pf:}$ Let $\epsilon>0$ be given. Let $\{q_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$. We can then define $F$ to be given as
$$F = [0,1] \setminus \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (q_i-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}},q_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}})$$
It is clear to see that $F \subset E$. We can now compute
\begin{eqnarray*}
m(E \setminus F) &=& m(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (q_i-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}},q_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}) \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \\
&=& m(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (q_i-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}},q_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}})) - m(\mathbb{Q}) \\ 
&=& m(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (q_i-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}},q_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}})) \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^\infty \vert q_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}} - (q_i-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}})  \vert \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^i} \\
&<& \epsilon
\end{eqnarray*}
as needed.
$\blacksquare$

Are all my steps correct? Or for my very last step to get inequality do I need to define the $F$ as $q_i$ minus $\frac{\epsilon}{2^{I+2}}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first and fourth equalities need to be inequalities, and the inequality on the last line needs to be an equality.

The second equality feels a bit strange to me.  It's true, but only because $\mathbb{Q}$ is a null set; generally such an equality would not hold.

To be clear, I would write it as

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
m(E \setminus F) &\leq& m(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (q_i-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}},q_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}}) \setminus \mathbb{Q}) \\
&\leq& m(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty (q_i-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}},q_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}})) \\
&\leq& \sum_{i=1}^\infty \vert q_i+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}} - (q_i-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i+1}})  \vert \\
&=& \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{\epsilon}{2^i} \\
&=& \epsilon
\end{eqnarray*}$$

If you really want a strict inequality in this formulation, it comes in both the first and third lines, but while not hard to show, neither is immediate; you'd need to show this.  If you want a strict inequality more simply, your idea of shrinking the open sets would work.